# remove every other string entry

Tags: java, string

I have collected som data from an XML file and I am now trying to edit the data so that it fits to my program. The data which I collect state the minimum and maximum value of a given parameter, however I am only interested in either the minimum or maximum values.

The XML data source looks like:

```
<tolerated>
    <UMIN2> [ 181.2 186.8 ] </UMIN2>
    <T_UMIN2> [ 0.4 0.6 ] </T_UMIN2>
    <UMIN1> [ 197 203 ] </UMIN1>
    <T_UMIN1> [ 2.4 2.6 ] </T_UMIN1>
    <UMAX1> [ 249.2 256.8 ] </UMAX1>
    <T_UMAX1> [ 0.9 1.1 ] </T_UMAX1>
    <UMAX2> [ 260 268 ] </UMAX2>
    <T_UMAX2> [ 0.4 0.6 ] </T_UMAX2>
</tolerated>
```

I have gotten my program to load this data into a string called tol, via this code

```
public static String tolerance() throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException{
     DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(O1.replace("\\","\\\\"));
        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();

        String tTemp = new String();

        XPathExpression expr1 = xpath.compile("ptfGen/body/gridCode/"+header2.substring(31,header2.length()-23)+"/tolerated");
        Node nodeGettingChanged1 = (Node) expr1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

        String toldata = new String();

        NodeList childNodes1 = nodeGettingChanged1.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i != childNodes1.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node child = (Node) childNodes1.item(i);
            if (!(child instanceof Element))
                continue;

            if (child.getNodeName().equals("tolerated"));{
                toldata = child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                tTemp += toldata.substring(3,toldata.length()-3).replace(" ", "\n") + "\n";
            }
            tol = tTemp;
        }
       return tTemp;
    }
```

This gives me all the values with a newline separation.

**My question is now can I/how can I remove every other entry so that I only have either the minimum or maximum values?**´

the output I am getting now is something like

tol = {"181.2\n186.8\n0.4\n0.6\n197\n.........."};

and what I amm looking for is

tol = {"181.2\n0.4\n197\n.........."};

Comment: I am not interested in changing the XML file, just the string.

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String), or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the minimum is always first and the maximum always second.

All you need to do is change

```
tTemp += toldata.substring(3,toldata.length()-3).replace(" ", "\n") + "\n";
```

to

```
tTemp += toldata.substring(3,toldata.length()-3).split(" ")[c] + "\n";
```

where `c` is 0 for the first (minimum) and 1 for the second (maximum).

or a simpler

```
tTemp += toldata.split(" ")[c] + "\n";
```

where `c` is 2 or 3 in the respective cases.

This of course assumes the string is always in the exact form: `" [ number number ] "` (always with exactly the same amount of spaces in the exact same positions). A simple [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) of `"\\s+"` instead of `" "` will allow one or more spaces instead, i.e.:

```
tTemp += toldata.split("\\s+")[c] + "\n";
```

`\s` means white-space and `+` means one or more. The additional `\` is to escape the `\` for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following:

1. Define a class to hold temps:

   ```
   public static class TempEntry {
       private final String min, max;

       public TempEntry(min, max){
           this.min = min;
           this.max = max;
       }

       public String getMin(){
           return min;
       }

       public String getMax(){
           return max;
       }
   }
   ```
2. When parsing, split the text in the nodes and create a new `TempEntry`
3. The parser could return either an immutable `List<TempEntry>` or a `TempEntry[]` array.
4. Now create a method or a new class that iterates through the list and pretty-prints it based on parameters (only mins, only max, both, etc)

This way you don't couple your parsing logic to your presentation logic (which may change more frequently).

Comment: I'm not saying the way it was done is great (it can definitely be more modular), but this is, in my opinion, overkill for such a simple problem.